# Как добавить гиперссылку на кнопку?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qpushbutton, гиперссылка

[image: Stylesheet]

Можно ли как-то через программу *Qt Designer* добавить на кнопку гиперссылку?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbFsP.jpg

Что это за строчка?

Comment: Предположим, что Qt Designera у нас нет. 
Теперь объясните лучше, что вы хотите сделать? 
Что значит добавить на кнопку гиперссылку?

Comment: @S.Nick хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку перебрасывало сразу на группу или страничку в вк (или любой другой источник)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> bool QDesktopServices::**openUrl**(const QUrl &url)
>
> Открывает указанный `URL-адрес` в соответствующем веб-браузере для среды рабочего стола пользователя и возвращает `True` в случае успеха; в противном случае возвращает `False`.
>
> Если `URL-адрес` является ссылкой на локальный файл (т.е. Схема URL-адреса - 'файл'), то он будет открыт в подходящем приложении вместо веб-браузера.

Попробуйте так:

**q1316237.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>292</width>
    <height>234</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    border: none;              /* Удалить границу */
}
#pushButton {
    background-color: #2196f3;
    /* Ограничьте минимальный размер */
    min-width:  96px;
    max-width:  96px;
    min-height: 96px;
    max-height: 96px;
    border-radius: 48px;        /* круглый */
}
#pushButton:hover {
    background-color: #64b5f6;
}
#pushButton:pressed {
    background-color: #bbdefb;
}</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Мой 
questions</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>292</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic


qtCreatorFile = "q1316237.ui"
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MyApp(QtBaseClass, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_link)

    def on_link(self):
        url = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1316237'
        QtGui.QDesktopServices.openUrl(QtCore.QUrl(url))        
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> И как вы сделали кнопку круглой?

StyleSheet:

```
QPushButton {
    border: none;              /* Удалить границу */
}
#pushButton {
    background-color: #2196f3;
    /* Ограничьте минимальный размер */
    min-width:  96px;
    max-width:  96px;
    min-height: 96px;
    max-height: 96px;
    border-radius: 48px;        /* круглый */
}
#pushButton:hover {
    background-color: #64b5f6;
}
#pushButton:pressed {
    background-color: #bbdefb;
}
```

Comment: я выше добавил скриншот, за что отвечает эта строчка? И как вы сделали кнопку круглой?

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер смотрите обновление в ответе.